# Insert values into array in C

Tags: c, arrays, insert

Wished Input ->

```
"Enter a word: program"
"Enter a postion to know where to start cutting: 2"
"Enter the following quantity to end up: 4"
```

Wished Output ->

```
ogra
```

This is my code, but I don't know how to insert values into a different array

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
int main (){

    char word[100], cutword[50];
    int on, off, i, j;

    printf("Entra a word: ");
    gets(word);
    printf("Enter a postion to know where to start cutting: ");
    scanf("%d", &on);
    printf("Enter the following quantity to end up: ");
    scanf("%d", &off);

    for (i = 0; i<strlen(word); i++){
        if (i >= on && i <= off) ¿cutword[]? = word[i];
    }

    for (j = 0; j<strlen(cutword); j++){
        printf("%c", cutword[j]);
    }

}
```

Comment: What is that **¿cutword[]?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
int k = 0;
int l = on + off;
for (i = on; i < l; i++){
    cutword[k++] = word[i];
}

for (j = 0; j < k; j++){
    printf("%c", cutword[j]);
}
```

Put some additional `if` to validate the input and check array boundaries before these loops.

Answer (score 0):

```
// if there is enough room in the buffers
if( strlen(word) > off) {
   // copy from    word + (offset) 
   //      to  cutword[0] 
   //      off number of characters
   memcpy(cutword, word + on, off ); 
}
```

thats if you want from position 2 get 4 characters

your code gets position 2 to position 4.

Comment: and without a a prepared function how would it be?

Comment: @frankie3 you for loop only considers `on` until `off` or word[2] through word[4] .. if you replace the for loop in your code with memcpy it will move all 4 character at one time as opposed to one ata time.

Answer (score 0):

Problem is with your first `for` loop. Iterate it only up to `off + on` and replace your `¿cutword[]? = word[i];` part with `cutword[j++] = word[i];` 
Try this

```
for (j = 0; i = 0; i < off + on; i++){
    if (i >= on && i <= off)
        cutword[j++] = word[i];
}
cutword[j] = '\0';
puts(cutword);
```